# Create symbolic links to files using wildcards

Tags: bash, shell, symlink, wildcards

I want to create symlinks to multiple files:

```
ln -s dev-*.php 's/dev-(.*\.php)/$1/'

Results hoped for:  
    site.php links to dev-site.php  
    file.php links to dev-file.php
```

What's the most concise way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

Well, if it's all in the same directory you could do something like this in bash or any other Bourne-style/POSIX shell:

```
for FILE in dev-*; do ln -s "$FILE" "${FILE#dev-}"; done
```

which would create symlinks without "dev-" to files beginning with "dev-".

Comment: Looks like the code formatter doesn't like the ${param#word} format.  In this context the # is not treated as a comment but as an instruction to remove dev- from the value stored in FILE

Comment: Just have to take care with file names with funny characters... and the `${FILE#dev-}` is a bashishm, AFAIU (definitely not in `/bin/sh` on Solaris way back).

Comment: @vonbrand, `${FILE#dev-}` is not Bourne, but is POSIX (was introduced by ksh, not bash). You need `--` for `ln` to mark the end of options for a `*` pattern, or better, use a `dev-*` pattern. The code as it is would create symlinks to themselves in every subdirectory of the current directory whose name doesn't start with `dev-`. See also the notes in my answer.

Comment: Thanks to all, for your help & explanations. Adding `dev-*` instead of `*` worked as intended here - as the code stands above it tries to create symlinks for _every_ file.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use a brief one-liner.

```
for file in dev-*.php; do ln -s $file $(echo "$file" | sed 's/^dev-//'); done
```

This cycles through the 'dev-*.php' files, getting the new name without 'dev-', then creating the symlink.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you'd do:

```
autoload zmv # typically in ~/.zshrc
zmv -Lsv 'dev-(*.php)' '$1'
```

With `bash` or other POSIX shells (including `zsh`):

```
for f in dev-*.php; do
  ln -s "$f" "${f#dev-}"
done
```

Note that if `site.php` exists and is a directory (or a symlink to a directory), then you may end up with a `dev-site.php` symlink inside it. With GNU `ln` you could add the `-T` option to guard against that (with `zmv` use `-o -T` to pass the `-T` option down to `ln`).